# Vue after login send to home page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm new to Vue, created one application without the login page and it's navigating perfectly with the router. Now I need to add a login page for this application, I'm planning two approaches, kindly confirm me which is the correct approach.

1. Instead of loading the App.vue page from main.js, directly load Login.vue page from here send to App.vue page after success login. Here how to send to App.vue page because login page won't contain router-view
2. Login.vue page also add in the router as / URL and from main.js load App.vue here App will contain router-view so default it will go to Login.vue page, from here I can navigate easily to the home page but App.vue contain header and footer these should not come for login page, how to avoid this

Comment: Use the second approach, so that you can later redirect to login if user logs out or session expires. For header and footer, add a IsLoggedIn property in app and use `v-if` on them.

Comment: you can add login page in different div and header and footer in different div and a v-if statement on both if wanna load login set login v-if value to true and header and footer value to false and vise versa. like this way header and footer won't load in your in your app.vue component if you are loading login.vue

Comment: Thank you Mat J and Naveen Kashyap

Comment: @MatJ got another challenge, I'm putting IsLoggedIn information globally by using Vue.prototype.$userLoggedIn = false and this global variable directly not able to use in v-if so placed in data(){return {userLoggedIn: Vue.prototype.$userLoggedIn}} . After loggedIn in Login.vue chaning global variable to true but it won't change App.vue data right so after success login, not able to see the menu. how to change App.vue data from Login.vue

Comment: Use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for global store